# when Mediaplayer is done, return to previous screen

Tags: android, listview, service, android-activity, media-player

I currently have a `service` with a `mediaplayer`. What I would like to do is when there are no more songs to play, it simply returns to the previous screen, in this case a `listview`. I added a `finish();` but that just seems to ANR the app. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I am calling the intent from inside a service.

Comment: can you do it from the activity which is calling the service?

Comment: so implement something so that when the service is done, it sends something to the activity and then start the new activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a event dispatcher on the service that can report back to your activity when there is nothing else to play. Or a listener on the activity when each song is done playing. Then you can tell the activity to do whatever you want, `finish()` or go to a new activity using intent.